# How to show image with 100% and custom height for all screen size

Tags: html, css

I have a horizontal slider which i need to make responsive so that the images used in it can take the size of any screen available.The problem that i am facing here is that the images are getting cut from right side of the Screen which i don't want.

Here is my HTML..

```
    <div id="sliderFrame">
    <div id="slider">
        <img src="images/1.jpg" style="width:100%;" alt="" />
        <img src="images/2.jpg" style="width:100%;" alt="" />   
    </div>
    </div>
```

And Here is my Full CSS.I am sorry if the Css is too long but seriously i was not able to find out that which property i should change to get the result.

```
 #sliderFrame 
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
}

#slider, #slider div.sliderInner {
width:100%;height:306px;/* Must be the same size as the slider images */
}

#slider {
background:#fff url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto; /*center-aligned*/
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
box-shadow: 0px 1px 5px #999999;
}

/* image wrapper */
#slider a.imgLink, #slider div.video {
z-index:2;
position:absolute;
top:0px;left:0px;border:0;padding:0;margin:0;
width:100%;height:100%;
}
#slider .video {
background:transparent url(video.png) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}

/* Caption styles */
#slider div.mc-caption-bg, #slider div.mc-caption-bg2 {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
height:auto;
padding:10px 0;/* 10px will increase the height.*/
left:0px; /*if the caption needs to be aligned from right, specify by right instead of left. i.e. right:20px;*/
bottom:0px;/*if the caption needs to be aligned from top, specify by top instead of bottom. i.e. top:150px;*/
z-index:3;
overflow:hidden;
font-size: 0;
}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg 
{
/* NOTE: Its opacity is to be set through the sliderOptions.captionOpacity setting in the js-image-slider.js file.*/
background:Black;/* or any other colors such as White, or: background:none; */
}
#slider div.mc-caption-bg2 {
background:none;
}
#slider div.mc-caption {
font: bold 14px/20px Arial;
color:#EEE;
z-index:4;
text-align:center;
background:none;
}
#slider div.mc-caption a {
color:#FB0;
}
#slider div.mc-caption a:hover {
color:#DA0;
}


/* ------ built-in navigation bullets wrapper ------*/
/* Note: check themes\2\js-image-slider.css to see how to hide nav bullets */
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper  {
top:320px;/* Its position is relative to the #slider */
text-align:center;
background:none;
position:relative;
z-index:5;
}

/* each bullet */
#slider div.navBulletsWrapper div 
{
width:11px; height:11px;
font-size:0;color:White;/*hide the index number in the bullet element*/
background:transparent url(bullet.png) no-repeat 0 0;
display:inline-block; *display:inline; zoom:1;
overflow:hidden;cursor:pointer;
margin:0 6px;/* set distance between each bullet*/
}

#slider div.navBulletsWrapper div.active {background-position:0 -11px;}


/* --------- Others ------- */

#slider div.loading 
{
width:100%; height:100%;
background:transparent url(loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
filter: alpha(opacity=60);
opacity:0.6;
position:absolute;
left:0;
top:0; 
z-index:9;
}

#slider img, #slider>b, #slider a>b {
position:absolute; border:none; display:none;
}

#slider div.sliderInner {
overflow:hidden; 
-webkit-transform: rotate(0.000001deg);/* fixed the Chrome not crop border-radius bug*/
position:absolute; top:0; left:0;
}

#slider>a, #slider video, #slider audio {display:none;}
```

This is the image of the screenshot which is not displaying as the complete image it is cut from the right end of the original image 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make images responsive use widely used code snippet for img tags

```
#slider > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Do i need to remove something from my .css file code or add this code along with that

Comment: Can you make screenshot or example in jsfiddle?

Comment: Image screenshot i have added in the post.Please have a look.

Comment: Seems like you do not use reset styles & in a result body has margins. Try to use `body {margin:0;}`

Comment: I updated with even that but same result ..Can you show me what css exactly i need to change in order to get the things done

Comment: There possible two cases why your images are not window size wide: 1. Images resolutions are smaller than width of window. So you need to make images `width: 100%`. 2. Remove margin from body using this code `body {margin:0;}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58781/discussion-between-user3816352-and-neilhem).